# How to run TFLite model(AutoML Vision Edge) with TFJS on the browser

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow.js, google-cloud-automl, tensorflowjs-converter

I trained a model with AutoML Vision Edge.
I want to infer a image on the browser.

input_format of tensorflowjs_converter not supported TFLite.
The tflite_convert command cannot convert to a model other than TFLite.

How to run TFLite model(AutoML Vision Edge) with TFJS on the browser?

Comment: Currently, tflite models cannot be run with tfjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TensorFlow.js model export](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/tensorflow-js-tutorial?hl=en_US) is already available in AutoML Vision. Just note as of today, this export like many others are still in a pre-release state and might be buggy or change or have limited support.